# Swift cloudkit CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions can't return delete record

Tags: swift, icloud, record, cloudkit

I don't know why I can't get any delete record on `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions`, I can get created and modified records, but `delete` just can't get delete the record.
On yesterday, I can get delete change record normally.

Here is my code

```
public func handleNotification(whichNotification : Int) {

    zoneID = UserDataCustomZone.zoneID

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        // Use the ChangeToken to fetch only whatever changes have occurred since the last
        // time we asked, since intermediate push notifications might have been dropped.
        var changeToken: CKServerChangeToken? = nil
        let changeTokenData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: serverChangeTokenKey)

        if changeTokenData != nil {
            changeToken = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: changeTokenData!) as! CKServerChangeToken?
        }

        let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOptions()
        options.previousServerChangeToken = changeToken
        let optionsMap = [zoneID!: options]
        let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: [zoneID!], optionsByRecordZoneID: optionsMap)
        operation.fetchAllChanges = true
        // only can receive created and modified change record
        operation.recordChangedBlock = { record in
           //show record
            print("check this out \(record)")

            }

    }

    operation.recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock = { zoneID, changeToken, data in

        print("print Token \(String(describing: changeToken))")

        guard let changeToken = changeToken else {
            return
        }

        let changeTokenData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: changeToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(changeTokenData, forKey: self.serverChangeTokenKey)
    }

    operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { zoneID, changeToken, data, more, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        guard let changeToken = changeToken else {
            return
        }

        let changeTokenData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: changeToken)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(changeTokenData, forKey: self.serverChangeTokenKey)
    }

    operation.fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock = { error in
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
    }

    operation.qualityOfService = .utility

    let container = CKContainer.default()
    let db = container.privateCloudDatabase
    db.add(operation)

     } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
```

Comment: And I can get Subscription remote notification when I delete data on Cloudkit.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have defined a [recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation/1640422-recordzonechangetokensupdatedblo) handler, which is enough for receiving records creations and updates. But, a [CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation) notifies records deletions via its [recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation/1640470-recordwithidwasdeletedblock) handler. The declaration is:

`var recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock: ((CKRecordID, String) -> Void)? { get set }`

So, basically you need to include following extra lines:

`operation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { recordID, recordType in ... }`

in your original code.

See [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchrecordzonechangesoperation/1640470-recordwithidwasdeletedblock) for reference.

The whole process and reference code can be found in section [Fetching Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW7), chapter [Maintaining a Local Cache of CloudKit Records](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html) of [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart) guide.